# How to toggle the menu bar on

Tags: visual-studio-code

Okay, really stupid question here: I toggled the menu bar off, using the view menu option. Now I would like to get it toggled back on but can't figure that out.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code How to Restore Menu Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701955/vs-code-how-to-restore-menu-bar)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and toggle it back again

Comment: This currently does not work. If it doesn't for you see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (1.55.2) the Alt key does not bring back the menu. But you can use Ctrl-Shift-p to get a list of all commands. Search for menu and toggle it.

```
View: Toggle menu bar
```

This was tested on a VM just after installing Vscode from https//code.visualstudio.com without customizing, other then hiding menu und activity bar.

It might be an internationalisation problem. Typing this in a German-language windows installation.

And by the way this is not a stupid question. I spend quite some time on this.