# visual studio code does not show property manager

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Visual Studio Code v1.25.1 on 64-bit Ubuntu. I am trying to set the add an image file to a visual studio project and set its properties to be always copied.

However, I do not

1. See Tools or Options in my main menu bar
2. Have any way of creating a project
3. Right clicking on a file does not show an option to edit properties.

What am I missing?  Previous answers have suggested using Tools->Customize or Views-> Other Views. AS I mentioned, I do not see a Tools option and View does not have an Other Views sub-option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a config file that you can manually manipulate, however maybe this post will help you [VS Code How to Restore Menu Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701955/vs-code-how-to-restore-menu-bar)

Comment: Thanks, @Eldlabs. This is not quite my problem, though it's useful for future reference. I see my menu bar alright. Visual studo code just seems to be missing some options in that menu bar which are availabel with visual studio in windows