# VSCode how do I get the menu back?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In Vscode I've switched of the Menu but cannot get it back on. There is no response to the Alt key.

Comment: Did you try pressing `Ctrl + P`, typing `View: Toggle Menu Bar`, and then hitting enter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore the menu bar in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701955/how-to-restore-the-menu-bar-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: the Menu item View / Appearance / Show Menu Bar currently sets menubarVisibility to compact instead of toggle. This probably is a bug. My answer below will work around this

Comment: @FelixSchütz I clicked view / appearance / Show Menu Bar once

Comment: Pressing Alt should get the menu bar back temporarily but it does not as the setting menubarVisibility is set to compact not toggle.

Comment: I updated the incorrect Visual Studio Code documentation to reflect current behaviour. You'll find it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

Answer (score 1):

Type Ctrl+Shift+P type "menu" select "View: Toggle Menu Bar" and the menu bar should be back. If not, leave a note.

Answer (score 0):

The setting can be changed in the global settings.json : Start this

```
%AppData%\code\User\settings.json
```

By pressing Ctrl+o in vscode. Replace the line that reads

```
"window.menuBarVisibility": "compact"
```

with

```
"window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle"
```